# How do I loop over this in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have this in defaults/main.yml

```
aws_efs_mount:
- "10.22.x.1": "us-east-1c.fs-123jha23.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/"
- "10.22.x.2": "us-east-1c.fs-97c3hw43.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/"
- "10.22.x.3": "us-east-1c.fs-76etgc22.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/"
```

how do I iterate over it? so I can do this

```
- name: Show key/value pair
  debug: msg="Key is {{ ??? }} and value is {{ ??? }}"
  with_???: "{{ aws_efs_mount }}"
```

If I use, with_items, and use item.key, I get "item has no attribute named key", and if I use with_dict, I get "with_dict expects a dict"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are specifying an array of dicts and it's not a set, why not make the dict more detailed?

```
aws_efs_mount:
- { ip: "10.22.x.1", mount: "us-east-1c.fs-123jha23.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/"}
- { ip: "10.22.x.2", mount: "us-east-1c.fs-97c3hw43.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/"}
- { ip: "10.22.x.3", mount: "us-east-1c.fs-76etgc22.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/" }


- name: Show key/value pair
  debug: msg="Key is {{ item.ip }} and value is {{ item.mount }}"
  with_items: "{{ aws_efs_mount }}"
```